# How can I manually notify the Framework of property changes when using the Breeze.Sharp.BaseEntity class?

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged, breeze-sharp

I have been using the `Breeze.Sharp.BaseEntity` base class at work for some time and up until now, have been ok with using their `GetValue` and `SetValue` properties for plugging into the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. However, occasionally, it is advantageous to notify of changes to multiple properties at once from a single property. Let me give you a simple example.

Let's say that we have a simple sum to perform. We have an `ItemAmount` property, an `ItemQuantity` property, and a `Total` property. Each time either of the `ItemAmount` or `ItemQuantity` property values change, we also want the total to update. Traditionally, we could do that like this:

```
public double ItemAmount
{
    get { return _itemAmount; }
    set 
    {
        _itemAmount = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ItemAmount");            
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Total");
    }
}

public int ItemQuantity
{
    get { return _itemQuantity; }
    set 
    {
        _itemQuantity = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ItemQuantity");            
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Total");
    }
}

public double { get => ItemAmount * ItemQuantity; }
```

This would make the Framework also update the value of the `Total` property as either property changed, as required. However, I can find no such way to call the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface using their base class, as unbelievably, they seem to have hidden access to their implementation of it.

So, my question is *How can I manually notify the Framework of property changes when using the `Breeze.Sharp.BaseEntity` class?*

Is there some way to connect to their implementation that I haven't worked out yet? When I added my own implementation, it didn't seem to connect with the Framework and did not notify of changes successfully. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no simple answer, but the way that I found to do this, was to clone the [Breeze.Sharp repository](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.sharp) and to make the following changes. In the `Breeze.Sharp.Standard` solution, open the `EntityAspect.cs` class and simply add your desired method to raise the `PropertyChanged` event handler, that is already declared in that class:

```
public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Then, you can call it from your `BaseEntity` class like this:

```
public int ItemQuantity
{
    get => GetValue<int>();
    set
    {
        SetValue(value);
        EntityAspect.NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Total));
    }
}
```

Note that changes to the `ItemQuantity` property are raised inside the `SetValue` method.